# React change className in x second if a specific className is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and I'm trying to create a simple reaction time app. I got stuck a little and I don’t know how to solve it. I could solve it to change the className on click, but I'd like to add a function that runs only if the "game-area-off" is active and it should change the classname to "game-area-on" at random times between 3-6 seconds.
So far i have come up with the code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true, gameClass: "game-area-start" };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn,
      gameClass: state.isToggleOn ? "game-area-off" : "game-area-start",
      
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.gameClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h1 className="default-text">
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? "Click anywhere to start" : "Wait for green"}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `handleClick` callback you can use a timeout with a random delay to toggle the "game-area-on" state.

```
const randomDelay = Math.random() * 3000 + 3000;
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    // set go state
  });
}, randomDelay);
```

I suggest using two pieces of state, 1 to track when the app is waiting to display the "on" value, and the second to display it. Additionally, the classname can be derived from the state, so it doesn't really belong there since it's easily computed in the render method.

Here is suggested code:

```
class ReactionTime extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gameRunning: false,
    isToggleOn: false,
    startTime: 0,
    endTime: 0
  };

  // timeout refs
  clearOutTimer = null;
  gameStartTime = null;

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // clear any running timeouts when the component unmounts
    clearTimeout(this.clearOutTimer);
    clearTimeout(this.gameStartTime);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    if (this.state.gameRunning) {
      // handle end click
      if (this.state.isToggleOn) {
        clearTimeout(this.clearOutTimer);
        this.setState({
          gameRunning: false,
          isToggleOn: false,
          endTime: performance.now()
        });
      }
    } else {
      // handle start click - reaction "game" started
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        gameRunning: true,
        isToggleOn: false,
        startTime: 0,
        endTime: 0
      }));

      // set timeout to display "on"
      const randomDelay = Math.random() * 3000 + 3000;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          isToggleOn: true,
          startTime: performance.now()
        });
      }, randomDelay);

      // reaction "game" timeout to reset if user is too slow
      this.clearOutTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          gameRunning: false,
          isToggleOn: false,
          startTime: 0,
          endTime: 0
        });
      }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { gameRunning, isToggleOn, startTime, endTime } = this.state;
    const className = gameRunning
      ? isToggleOn
        ? "game-area-on"
        : "game-area-off"
      : "game-area-start";

    const reactionTime = Number(endTime - startTime).toFixed(3);
    return (
      <div className={className} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h1 className="default-text">
          {gameRunning
            ? isToggleOn
              ? "Go!"
              : "Wait for green"
            : "Click anywhere to start"}
        </h1>
        {reactionTime > 0 && <div>Reaction Time: {reactionTime}ms</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-change-classname-in-x-second-if-a-specific-classname-is-active]